# Yeoman + Grunticon: Gruntfile.js problems

Tags: javascript, svg, gruntjs, yeoman, yeoman-generator

So i'm trying to use **grunticon** into my `yo webapp` (yeoman) but it says it cannot read any files.

**Gruntfile.js:**

```
   svgmin: {
        dist: {
            files: [{
                expand: true,
                cwd: '<%= config.app %>/images/svg-src/',
                src: '{,*/}*.svg',
                dest: '<%= config.dist %>/images/svg-src/'
            }]
        }
   },
   grunticon: {
         myIcons: {
               options: {
                   src: '<%= config.app %>/images/svg-src/',
                   dest: '<%= config.app %>/images/svg-dist/'
               }
         }
   },
```

Full Gruntfile.js: https://gist.github.com/ricardobanegas/6c8c4ad3ac57f49728d7

Patch: https://gist.github.com/ricardobanegas/7f2933bfb8e58d7ef30c

**Unix:**

```
$ grunt grunticon:myIcons
Running "grunticon:myIcons" (grunticon) task
Look, it's a grunticon!
Grunticon has no files to read!

Done, without errors.
```

So the question is really, why is Gruntfile.js not finding my images inside `app/images/svg-src/`?

**References:**

[Grunticon](https://github.com/filamentgroup/grunticon)

[Yeoman+Grunticon install guidelines](http://www.gpmd.co.uk/blog/front-end-process-flat-builds-and-automation-part-3-grunt-tasks/)

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was changed since version 1.0.0: https://github.com/filamentgroup/grunticon#whats-changed-in-this-major-version

Looks like I was following an old tutorial. Using `files: []` instead of `options: {}` solved the problem:

```
grunticon: {
    myIcons: {
        files: [{
            expand: true,
            cwd: '<%= config.app %>/images/svg-src/',
            src: '{,*/}*.svg',
            dest: '<%= config.dist %>/images/svg-dist/'
         }],

         options: {

         }
        }
    },
```

Answer (score 0):

`src` must point to actual files, not just a folder.

```
src: '<%= config.app %>/images/svg-src/*.svg'
```

Comment: I thought it was good practice to separate `cwd` and `src` in Gruntfile.js?